# boost::variant gives wrong result when bool appears as possible type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

The code that works is the following:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::map<std::string, boost::variant<int, std::string> > values;
    values["a"] = 10;
    values["b"] = "bstring";
    values["c"] = "cstring";


    for (const auto &p : values) {
            std::cout <<  p.first <<  " = ";

        if (p.second.type() == typeid(std::string)) {
            std::cout <<  boost::get<std::string>( p.second ) << " (found string)" << std::endl;
        } else if ( p.second.type() == typeid(int)) {
            std::cout << boost::get<int>( p.second ) << " (found int)" << std::endl;
        } else if ( p.second.type() == typeid(bool)) {
            std::cout << boost::get<bool>( p.second ) << " (found bool)" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << " not supported type " << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
```

The output (g++ test.cpp -std=c++11):

```
a = 10 
b = bstring 
c = cstring
```

The code that does not work is exactly the same, except the line that defines the std::map

modifying the line of the map definition to:

```
std::map<std::string, boost::variant<int, std::string, bool> > values;
```

the output is different:

```
a = 10
b = c =
```

The if statement that refers to std::string comparison does not succeed. What is the problem?

Comment: The branch that outputs `bool` values is missing.

Comment: What you mean? I need to update my boost system? (using 1.55)

Comment: `if (p.second.type() == typeid(bool))` is missing.

Comment: No, this is not the problem. I have updated my question with the missing if statement.

Comment: It does output `b = 1 (found bool) c = 1 (found bool)` for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `values["b"] = "bstring";` creates a `bool` value, when both `std::string` and `bool` are in the variant type.

A fix is `values["b"] = std::string("bstring");`.

Or, in [C++14](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s):

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
values["b"] = "bstring"s;
```

---

It is a well-known annoyance that string literals better convert to `bool` than to `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void f(std::string) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
void f(std::string const&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
void f(bool) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

int main() {
    f("hello");
}
```

Outputs:

```
void f(bool)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to mention [`operator""s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).